# Fortran `read(*,*)` in a DLL causes "run time error(39)" when called from VB6.0

Tags: debugging, dll, vb6, fortran, runtime-error

Code in VB6.0 is:

```
Private Declare Sub suba Lib "D:\try_vb\c_dll\Dll1\Dll1\Debug\Dll1.dll" (ByRef a As Single, ByRef b As Single, ByRef c As Single)
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim a As Single
    Dim b As Single
    Dim c As Single
    a = 10#
    b = 2#
    Call suba(a, b, c)
    Text1.Text = c
End Sub
```

Code in Fortran's DLL is:

```
subroutine suba(a,b,c)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES stdcall,DLLEXPORT ::suba
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:"suba"::suba
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES reference :: a,b,c
    implicit none
    real::a
    real::b
    real::c
    real::aaa

    c=a+b
    read(*,*)aaa       !This sentence seems wrong
end subroutine
```

If the line `read(*,*)aaa` doesn't exist, the program can return the right answer `c=12`, see below:
[image: Fig 1]

But when `read(*,*)aaa` exists, an error happens, that is

```
forrtl:severe(39):error during read,unit -4,file CONIN$
```

[image: forrtl:severe(39):error during read,unit -4,file CONIN$]

What should I do?

Comment: What is the linking model for fortran /MD or /MT?  The read is attempting to read from the console.  It would be better if you handled all reads from VB and just did computations in Fortran.

Comment: I cannot recommend mixing I/O from two different languages. Only one should read and write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple - the Fortran code is trying to read from the console, and there isn't one in a VB application. Generally you should do all your I/O in one language. You can call the Windows API routine AllocConsole to create a console before doing the READ in Fortran, but that seems silly for a VB app that has a graphic interface.

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate method is to do all I/O in one language(like helpers said).

Howerver,as a temporary solution,I find the function "AllocConsole()" can avoid the errors because a console window can be set.